# including pygame to an environment using virtualenv

Tags: python, pygame, virtualenv

i have already Python 3.2.3 , but i must install Python 3.3.2 for some stuff in a course , and my old codes are related to pygame which is installed on my computer, i want to use virtualenv after installing it and i installed pip also , i don't know how to include pygame to each environments either python 3.3.2 or python 3.2.3 , i am using windows xp , here what i did so far.

```
 C:\>virtualenv -p C:\Python32\python.exe env_py32
 C:\>env_py32\Scripts\activate
 (env_py32) C:\>pip.exe install pygame
```

but it wasn't installed , and i got this error.

```
error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed
with exit status 2
```

any help or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to compile the C-libraries. The reason for that is that there is no pre-compiled version of Pygame for Python 3.3. So you need to install a c-compiler.

Comment: pygame was working fine with python 3.2.3 , and still working fine , but when i installed virtualenv and created the environment env_py32 i  ended with this error , i removed python 3.3.2 before trying what i did above.